# Query of queries outside ColdFusion

Tags: sql, coldfusion, qoq

My experience of using Adobe ColdFusion, even if still somewhat limited, was absolutely joyful and pleasant.

Of all good things I could say about ColdFusion, one feature completely blew me off my feet. It might be neither very effective, or useful in production, but anyway, I am talking about the so-called "query of queries" feature, or the `dbtype="query"` attribute of `cfquery`. It allows you to run SQL statements against arbitrary datasets, not just a database connection. You can, for example, join a resultset, that you've just retrieved from the database and an in-memory structure (that is, of course, subject to certain limitations). It provides a quick-and-dirty way to kind of "post-process" the data, which can sometimes be much more readable (and flexible, too!), than, say, iterating through the dataset in a loop.

However, ColdFusion is not a very popular product and I am not going to go over the reasons why it is like that. What I am asking is, is there any support for this technique in other languages (like a library, that does more or less the same)? Python? Perl? Ruby? PHP? Anything? Because, to me it seems, that the potential of this feature is huge, maybe not in production code, but it is an absolute life-saver if you need to test something quickly. Needless to say, the SQL ColdFusion uses for this is somewhat limited, to my knowledge, but still, the idea is still great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't find anything that handles data as well as ColdFusion then remember it plays very well with other programming languages. You can always do the heavy query processing in CF then just wrap your processing logic in remote CFCs and expose them as web services serving up JSON.

That will let you benefit from what you find great about ColdFusion while trying out some other languages.

If you need to get away from CF try SqlAlchemy in Python, or like other posters said Rails and LINQ are worth playing with.

Comment: Oh yes, I've read up on SqlAlchemy and it seems, that it is exactly what I want! As for using coldfusion in tandem with applications, that are written in another languages, - yes, we've done it before, but sometimes using coldfusion is just not an option.

Comment: If/when ColdFusion is not an option, does that also exclude Railo or OpenBD ? (with them being LGPL and GPLv3 respectively)

Answer (score 3):

i can't for python, ruby, perl, php. however .Net has something called [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) which is essentially QoQ on steroids.

Comment: Oh yes, I should've mentioned LINQ in my original post. Unfortunately, I do not ever get to code in .Net as it is not used in the environment I work in so I don't have any experience with it whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of frameworks use object-relational mapping (ORM), which will convert your database tables to objects.

For example, using Rails you fetch data from a model instead of directly talking to the database. Queries, or finds, are returned as array objects, which can in turn be queried themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this in .NET by using LINQ. LINQ will let you query objects as well as databases.

Answer (score 0):

In doing performance analysis of Query of Queries, I was surprised by their execution time, I could not get them to return in less than 10ms in my tests, where simply queries to the actual database would return in 1ms or less.  My understanding (at least in CF MX 7) is that while this is a useful function, it is not a highly optimized one.  I found it to be much faster to loop over the query manually doing conditional logic to replace what I was attempting to do with my query of queries.

That being said, it is faster than going to the database if the initial query is slow.  Just don't use it thinking that it is going to always be faster than doing a more creative sort or initial query as each QofQ is far from instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, there's three projects worth taking a look at, each with it's own positives and negatives, some more SQL like than others. JoSQL [JoSQL](http://josql.sourceforge.net/), [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/), and [MetaModel](http://eobjects.org/trac/wiki/MetaModel).

Maybe one of these day's I'll figure out how to call a QoQ directly from the Java underneath CF. ;)

Answer (score -15):

This technique (ColdFusion's query-of-queries) is one of the worst ideas out there. Not only does it keep business logic in the database, but it takes what little business logic you have left in your code and shoves it out to the database just for spite.

What you need is a *good language*, not bad techniques to make up for deficiencies.

Python and Ruby, as well as other languages not on your list such as C# and Haskell, have exceptional support for writing arbitrary and powerful queries against in-memory objects. This is in fact the technique that you want, not ColdFusion's query-of-queries. The technique of writing queries against in-memory objects is an aspect of a general style of programming called *functional programming*.

Comment: Since QofQs work against memory objects (other query results), they do exactly the opposite of what you imply.

Comment: They are sent to the database. CF takes an in memory QueryTable and sends it to the database as a subquery. The point is, the core of your application should be a rich domain model. It should not be the database.

Comment: QofQs do *NOT* get sent to the database as a subquery.

Comment: Note: You can prove this very simply by storing a query in the Application scope, taking down the database, then QofQ on that query - it works fine.

Comment: One of the benefits of CF's QofQ is that it allows you to, for example, have a large complex query cached, yet still be able to change the order of the in-memory query - exactly what you are referring to in your final paragraph.

Comment: In memory record sets can come from multiple datasources, so which database does ColdFusion send it to if you do a UNION? In memory record sets can also come from non database sources such as the cfdirectory tag which reads a directory, cfsearch which reads a verity collection, and cfldap which reads from an ldap server, so which database does coldfusion send these record sets to be subqueried when performing a QofQs?

Comment: You obviously don't "get" the feature... It doesn't have to hit a database server to do the QoQ. That's what makes it useful. You can, for instance, use CFFeed to get a query object of an RSS feed, and union it with some old content for that feed that you've saved to your database. Yes, the old data has to be read from the database, but the workflow is: read old data from DB into in-memory query object, read RSS feed into in-memory query object, and union them in memory without the assistance of a DBMS. If you're going to troll, at least be correct.

Comment: It seems you guys are right about QoQ. I had read elsewhere a review of the technique, and the CF docs are extraordinarily vague on the matter. I still have serious reservations about CF in general over of its affinity for QueryTables over domain models and its general lack of object-oriented or functional abstractions, but the fact that QoQ is actually a language and implementation of in-memory object (well, QueryTable) queries makes things better.